# Sublime text regular expression search and replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Using Sublime Text 3, I have a text file with many lines like this:

```
{"Currency" : "Andorran Franc","Code" : "ADF","USD/1 Unit" : "0.1853","Units/1 USD" : "5.3967"}
{"Currency" : "Andorran Peseta","Code" : "ADP","USD/1 Unit" : "0.007306","Units/1 USD" : "136.8890"}
```

For each line I would like to eliminate the "Currency" field and its value so that the lines look like:

```
{"Code" : "ADF","USD/1 Unit" : "0.1853","Units/1 USD" : "5.3967"}
{"Code" : "ADP","USD/1 Unit" : "0.007306","Units/1 USD" : "136.8890"}
```

but I have having trouble coming up with a regular expression to apply.

Comment: is that the currency field always at the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched chars with an empty string.

```
"Currency"\s*:\s*"[^"]*",
```

OR

```
"Currency"\s*:.*?,(?="[^"]*"\s*:)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sM5jU3/1)

Comment: or `"Currency"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"(?:[},])`

Answer (score 0):

```
"Currency"[^,]*,
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/13

If the format is fixed then it can be done in this simple way